# Python - How to change the font with MIMEText

Tags: python, email, fonts, size

I've got an automated mailing system with MIMEText, and I would like to change the font of the text in one line.
How do I do that, can you help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add code snippet?

Comment: What do you mean "font"? E-mails are either text, rich text, or HTML (mostly) and the font is up to the client reading the e-mail how they render (not the e-mail sender). If you mean bolden/emphasis, that can be done in the message itself, setting the MIME content-type to HTML.

Answer (score 2):

MIMEText will generate the mail in plaintext (which is generated in a monospaced font, and there's nothing you can do about it) and as HTML.

With HTML, you could simply wrap your e-mail in a `font` or `font face` (the last one, if you need to indicate only the font's family) tag:

`<font="Font Name Here">Your e-mail here</font>`

Obs: you can only accomplish that if your recipient is reading mail in an HTML capable email client.

Comment: My emails are correctly sending as plain text, but the font is not monospace. It's like Arial. Is there a setting to force monospace?

Answer (score 0):

MIMEText should support HTML tags, so you can just wrap `<font face="Font name">Text</font>` tags around it. This is of course assuming that your clients are reading the message with a client that will parse the HTML tags.